# Intrinsic content sized UICollectionView inside UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, intrinsic-content-size

Let me preface by saying that I've spent probably 100 hours over the past few months searching Google and StackOverflow trying to answer this question. I've followed many tutorials and have not been able to solve my problem. Every one is a major disappointment and is disheartening.

**Expectation**

[image: Expectation]

**Reality**

[image: Reality]

**Problem**

I have a UITableView that contains a UIView. The UIView has auto layout constraints to pin it 15pt off the edges of the cell, and then I give that a shadow and rounded corners. Inside that UIView, I have a few labels, then a UICollectionView, and a stack view.

My UICollectionView keeps having a height of 0 and I can't figure out how to make it have intrinsic size. The only way I can seem to make it display properly is to force a specific height to it via auto layout inside the storyboard (which is what I did to take this screenshot). Unfortunately, forcing a height like this is not realistic for 2 reasons:

1. The height varies based on the width of the device. Since the images are squares, the height is loosely (but not exactly) half the width of the device.
2. If there are no images, the height of the collection view should be 0.

It really seems like it should be possible to use the intrinsic content size of the flow layout here.

**Storyboard**

[image: Storyboard]

**Constraints**

I've got about 15pt of space between each of the labels, collection view, and stack view (so, the vertical space). The collection view prototype cell has an image view in it. The image view has top, bottom, trailing and leading space all set to 0 to the collection view cell, and also has a 1:1 ratio.

**Collection View Layout**

To achieve the layout of one large image and 4 small images, I'm using [SNCollectionViewLayout](https://github.com/ahmedAlmasri/SNCollectionViewLayout).

**Data Source / Delegate**

In my controller, in `viewDidLoad`, I've set the `estimatedRowHeight` of the UITableView to 400, and I've set the `rowHeight` to `UITableView.automaticDimension`.

In the tableView cellForRowAt, I dequeue a reusable custom `UITableViewCell` class, set various outlets on the table view cell, and call `reloadData()` on the collection view for the table view cell. In the storyboard, I've set the table view cell as the collection view's data source and delegate.

In the table view cell's `awakeFromNib` function, I've got it setting the corner radius, shadow, and using the following code for the flow layout on the collection view (which you can see in their example):

```
let snCollectionViewLayout = SNCollectionViewLayout()
snCollectionViewLayout.fixedDivisionCount = 4
snCollectionViewLayout.delegate = self
snCollectionViewLayout.itemSpacing = 10
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = snCollectionViewLayout
```

I've also implemented the optional `SNCollectionViewLayoutDelegate` protocol by writing the following function:

```
func scaleForItem(inCollectionView collectionView: UICollectionView, withLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UInt {
    if indexPath.row == 0 || collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section) <= 2 {
        return 2
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}
```

This function is why the first image is twice the height and width as the rest.

**Research**

In trying to figure this out, I've checked the `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize` inside the table view cell's cellForRowAt and willDisplay methods. In either case, it's (0,0).

I've also tried checking it in the collection view cell's cellForItemAt and willDisplay. Those log lines don't even print unless I add a height constraint to the collection view to force it tall, but then I don't have a good way to bring the height back down to what it should be, and any time I've tried, I got conflicting constraint warnings and really wonky stretched views (such as the stack view being totally squished).

In testing, I've forced a height constraint that's large enough for the collection view to fit, and when that happens, it renders correctly and the collection view content size is correct, so I know it's capable of keeping track (which can be seen [here](https://github.com/ahmedAlmasri/SNCollectionViewLayout/blob/master/SNCollectionViewLayout/Classes/SNCollectionViewLayout.swift#L156)).

Does anyone have any insight into this? I'd be happy to provide more code if you have any specifics on things to look into. I tried to give the full picture, while keeping this as short as possible (I know it's long).

I feel like the issue has something to do with the collection view being inside a table view cell.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout ? to give sizeForItemAt indexPath.

Comment: @HardikThakkar I have not, but I'm trying to get it to size automatically, instead of manually calculating the size myself. The SNCollectionViewLayout is supposed to calculate the width of each cell, based on the fact that I set it to be 4 columns, 10pt between cells, and the ratios I gave each cell (first one is 2x the size). By default, it makes each cell a square, by setting the height of the cell equal to the width that it calculated. https://github.com/ahmedAlmasri/SNCollectionViewLayout/blob/master/SNCollectionViewLayout/Classes/SNCollectionViewLayout.swift#L105

Comment: Also know that my first screenshot is actually a screenshot of the iOS simulator, but to get that I have to force the collection view to a height via the storyboard, and I'm trying to avoid figuring out how to manually calculate this. Collection views are capable of intrinsic content sizing, so I should be able to have it automatically size.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a height constraint connection in your table view cell.

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And update the height constraint value programatically as per height calculations

```
self. collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = 100 // set it to 0 if nothing to display
```

Comment: I've tried this sort of thing before. Exactly where do I set the height constraint? I had trouble figuring that out because I need it to have rendered the collection view, so that the flow layout has figured out the right height. Usually when I tried that, I got auto layout errors that said it had to break constraints. I'd be more than happy to try again if you tell me where to put that.

Comment: It has to be whenever you update tableview cell. You have to do this in datasource method `cellForRow` of your tableview (you should be reloading the collection view at that point too)

Comment: I am definitely reloading the collection view inside `cellForRowAt`, so no problem there, but the flow layout hasn't rendered yet, so I don't know what height to set it to yet. How do I figure out what to set the height to if the collection view layout hasn't done its work yet? Is there a way to force it to calculate its height? Or possibly a place to set the height constraint *after* the collection view has rendered?

Comment: @Nate how many different layout possibilities are there to determine the height

Comment: @agibson007 Well, 2 per device: 0px and nearly half the width of the screen. Though, the collection view flow layout is capable of figuring this out, so it would stand to reason that I'm missing something in getting it to just size itself based on content size.

Comment: @Nate does it need a height to calculate or are you saying it can do that without knowing the height. If so use that logic to set the height constraint mentioned in this answer. Or create a subclass view that overrides intrinsic size and use that logic in there and have the collectionview be a subview of that view.

Comment: @agibson007 By default, the SNCollectionViewLayout library makes the cells be squares. I just tell the layout how many columns I want (4), and how much space between each cell (10pt), and it figures out how big to make the cells. What's unclear though is how I should set the height of the UICollectionView itself. The example has a collection view that's the entire dimension of the screen, and the squares fill it nicely and it scrolls.

Comment: @agibson007 I'm trying to have the collection view take up a fairly small about of space (as can be seen in the screenshot). I have the width set via the constraints (15pt off all 4 edges of the table view cell), but I'd like to use the content size of the collection to determine its height. Any ideas on how do make a subclass to do that?